# How to add displayfield into the panel dynamically

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a json data like this.

```
var myObj = [{
    labl1 : "SomeVal1",
    labl2 : "SomeVal2",
    Value : "myVal1"
},{
    labl1 : "SomeVal1",
    labl2 : "SomeVal2",
    Value : "myVal1"
}]
```

I have to create two displayfield here and I created one item in my view that I need to fill.

What I am trying to do here is

```
var myPanel =this.down('#myPanel')
for(var i=0; i<myObj.length; i++){
    var myStr = myObj[i].labl1 + "\n" + myObj[i].labl2.labl2;
    var myObj = {
        xtype: 'displayfield',
        fieldLabel: myStr,
        value: myObj[i].Value,
    }
    myPanel.items.items.push(myObj);
}
myPanel.setHidden(false);
```

This is not adding an item. Can anyone suggest me how to add an item dynamically.
myPanel is

```
{
     xtype : 'panel',
     hidden : true,
     id : 'MessageNarrative',
     title: 'Message Details',
     layout: {
         type: "vbox",
         align: "stretch"
         },
     items: []
}
```

Comment: use myPanel.add(myObj) instead of  myPanel.items.items.push(myObj);

Comment: @JasminSolanki It worked. Can you make this to answer so I can accept this.

Answer (score 0):

use myPanel.add(myObj) instead of myPanel.items.items.push(myObj);